# Политика размера в qt

Tags: qt

Не могу понять политику размера в `Qt`, а именно как изменяется размещение виджетов в зависимости от политики: `Fixed`, `Minimum`, `Maximum`, `Preferred`, ..., `Ignored`.

Я пытался написать программу, в которой увидел бы то, что написано в документации, но мои результаты не совсем утешительны. Я не вижу разницы между `Expanding` и `MinimumExpanding`, а также при политике `Minimum` я все же могу уменшить `QPushButton` ниже его `sizeHint()`.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это скриншоты не рабочего окна программы, как я понимаю, а редактора. Но эти параметры вроде работают во время выполнения программы. Когда вы делаете виджет масштабируемый за формой, и определяете как он будет меняться с изменением размера формы. Разве не так?

Comment: Ну так. И что? При запуске программы то же самое.

Comment: Хотя нет, результаты немного отличаются. С Minimum теперь понятно, но все же не понятно с MinimumExpanding и Expanding

Comment: не все так просто, Карл. Все зависит еще от атрибута layoutSizeConstraint класса QLayout. Так например, при его значении SetNoConstraint результат программы такой же как в дизайнере, а при значении setMinimumSize результат уже другой

Comment: так же при вертикальной политике minimum я могу уменьшить размер виджета таким образом, что кнопки вообще пропадут